# paraemeters in url structure

Tags: jsp, url, struts

I've coded a website in Jsp/Struts. The application contains a profile for each user.

When a user wants to give his profile's link to others, he gives it like this : `www.my-site.com/profile?id=10010101`

Instead, i want to have the feature which twitter and facebook has.. like :`www.my-site.com/myusername`

Is this type of  url  for the user profile possible with struts / jsp  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the Struts part, but it's possible with just a servlet which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/` and extracts the `myusername` part by `request.getPathInfo().substring(1)`. You could then let this servlet forward to `/profile?id=xxxx` which could then be intercepted by Struts.

Comment: Wow! thats a good idea. I was thinking of handling it it using custom error pages.! For example,,   http://my-site.com/myprofile will be redirected to my custom error page and my custom error page should have some logic to redirect it to /profile?id=XXXX.